# how to use if else or true false in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements

```
def subst(A):

n = len(A) 
x = n*[0] 

for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
    s = sum([A[i][j]*x[j]
    for j in range(i+1,n)])
    if A[i][i]!=0:
        x[i] = (A[i][n] - s)/A[i][i]

    else:
        print("has no solution!")    
        break
return x
```

I've tried in several ways using Until While True but I'm not able to solve this problem, the purpose is to display the array only when it has solution, but even when it has no solution the program is displaying [0,0] along with the message error. How can I not display this [0,0]?

Comment: Hello! You should explain what your goal is, and try to fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Please make an effort to debug your own code. StackOverflow is not a debugging service. If you have a specific problem, feel free to narrow your code down and ask that question, but as written your question is not a good fit for this site. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The calling function needs to check the result.

Comment: Instead of breaking the loop, you should return instead. Otherwise x is still returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Don't break from else statement instead return empty string.

see:

```
def subst(A):

    n = len(A) 
    x = n*[0] 

    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        s = sum([A[i][j]*x[j]
        for j in range(i+1,n)])

        if A[i][i]!=0:
                x[i] = (A[i][n] - s)/A[i][i]

        else:
            print("has no solution!")    
            return ""
    return x

print(subst([[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]))
```